# Unable to use a variable to specify the targets for rsync's "--exclude={..}" option within script

Tags: bash, rsync, variable-substitution

My goal is to have my bash script run this command:

```
rsync -azhi --dry-run --exclude={'file1.txt','file2.txt','*.sql'} /from-directory/ /to-directory/
```

... when abstracted thusly:

```
srcdir='/from-directory/'
dstdir='/to-directory/'
excludes="{'file1.txt','file2.txt','*.sql'}"
rsync -azhi --dry-run --exclude="$excludes" "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
```

`$srcdir` and `$dstdir` evaluate correctly, but `$excludes` is not being interpreted as I had hoped it would. From the command line, --exclude={'file1.txt','file2.txt','*.sql'} works great. But once I try to stuff that {...} string into a variable, it stops working.

Comment: Can you edit your post to explain _how_ the behavior of `rsync` deviates from your expectation? Does the `exclude` option not work at all, or does it exclude, but in an unexpected way? Also, are you sure that a brace expansion will correctly work with the `exclude` option? Does it work when you run the command directly from the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an array.  For example:

```bash
excludes=(file1.txt file2.txt '*.sql')
rsync -azhi --dry-run $(printf -- "--exclude=%q " "${excludes[@]}") /from-directory/ /to-directory/
```

BTW, don't enclose `*.sql` in single-quotes if you **want** it to expand to all .sql files in the current dir.  I'm guessing that's NOT what you want it to do, so I've quoted it.

That will expand to:

```
rsync -azhi --dry-run --exclude=file1.txt --exclude=file2.txt --exclude=*.sql /from-directory/ /to-directory/
```

alternatively:

```
rsync -azhi --dry-run --exclude="$(printf -- "%q," "${excludes[@]}" |
    sed -e s/,$//)" /from-directory/ /to-directory/
```

will expand to:

```
rsync -azhi --dry-run --exclude=file1.txt,file2.txt,*.sql /from-directory/ /to-directory/
```

Comment: BTW, for `rsync` sometimes it's a lot easier to generate an include/exclude file (or use process substitution to emulate a file) and use `--exclude-from` instead of `--include` or `--exclude`.  See `man rsync` and search for `INCLUDE/EXCLUDE PATTERN RULES`

Comment: Thanks for the work-around that uses an array. That's clever! I'm still curious to know what my problem is when I just try to stuff the string {'file1.txt','file2.txt','*.sql'} into a variable and then use it later as an argument. Also, thanks for the suggestion of using an external file (which is a much better solution in my particular case.)

Comment: 1. That's one of the things arrays are for.  Putting command args into an array and using the `[@]` subscript to return them all as separate "words" is fairly standard/common usage.   2. The string `{'file1.txt','file2.txt','*.sql'}` didn't work because the shell just inserts the value of the variable as a literal, it doesn't expand it as it would if `{a,b,c,...}` were on the command line (not unless you use `eval` to force it to re-evaluate the line.  trouble is, `eval` is potentially very dangerous and insecure - in ways that expanding an array isn't).

Comment: @cas Using `$(printf ...%q ...)` won't work, because the quotes/escapes it adds won't get parsed (the shell parses quotes & escapes before expanding the command substitution, so by the time there're part of the command it's too late). Use `"${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=}"` instead; see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710476/bash-need-help-passing-a-a-variable-to-rsync/50710691#50710691).

Comment: @GordonDavisson must admit, I didn't test today's edit with `rsync`, just with `printf` alone.  I'll have to do some more testing before I decide whether `%q` is better or worse than `%s`.

Comment: @cas It'll work fine for `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, but `*.sql` will get an escape added, and that'll be passed to `rsync` as part of the pattern.

Comment: yeah, i noticed the `\*.sql`.  I'm not sure how rsync will deal with the * being escaped. will have to read rsync's man page again, later tonight when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

With `rc` and derivatives or `zsh -o rcexpandparam`:

```
excludes=(file1.txt file2.txt '*.sql')
rsync -azhi --dry-run '--exclude=- '$excludes $srcdir $dstdir
```

With `fish`:

```
set excludes file1.txt file2.txt '*.sql'
rsync -azhi --dry-run '--exclude=- '$excludes $srcdir $dstdir
```

With `zsh`:

```
excludes=(file1.txt file2.txt '*.sql')
rsync -azhi --dry-run '--exclude=- '$^excludes $srcdir $dstdir
```

(where `^` enables `rc`-style of expansion for that one array expansion).

With `ksh93`/`bash`/`zsh`:

```
excludes=(file1.txt file2.txt '*.sql')
rsync -azhi --dry-run "${excludes[@]/#/--exclude=- }" "$srcdir" "$dstdir"
```

Note that we use `'--exclude=- '` instead of `--exclude=` as otherwise, it wouldn't work if `$excludes` had some patterns such as `- *`, `+ *` or `!`. See `rsync` man page (emphasis mine):

```
       --exclude=PATTERN
              This  option  is  a  simplified form of the --filter option that
              defaults to  an  exclude  rule  and  does  not  allow  the  full
              rule-parsing syntax of normal filter rules.

[...]

       Note that the --include/--exclude command-line options do not allow the
       full range of rule parsing as described above -- they  only  allow  the
       specification of include/exclude patterns plus a "!" token to clear the
       list (and the normal comment parsing when rules are read from a  file).
       If  a  pattern  does  not  begin with "- " (dash, space) or "+ " (plus,
       space), then the rule will be interpreted as if "+ "  (for  an  include
       option) or "- " (for an exclude option) were prefixed to the string.  A
       --filter option, on the other hand, must always contain either a  short
       or long rule name at the start of the rule.
```