# Repeat flags with different values in same command

Tags: shell-script

I will try to keep it simple. I have a result from editing stream as follows using `sed` command:

```
filename_1  
filename_2  
.  
.  
filename_n
```

Now depending upon the number of files in the previous result I want to execute the command in shell as follows.

```
some_command --foo "filname_1" --foo "filename_2" --foo "filename_n" remaining_some_command
```

Where --foo is flag in between the command and filename_1...filename_n are its values depending on the result from `sed` .

It should be possible in shell. But how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use a variable to specify the targets for rsync's "--exclude={..}" option within script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658213/unable-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-the-targets-for-rsyncs-exclude-opt)

Answer (score 5):

So you have some command that produces a list of filenames, one per line, and you want to generate `--foo` and `filename` as command line arguments for each line produced?

E.g. with `printf` and `echo` to print some lines and take the args:

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    args+=(--foo "$filename")
done < <(printf "test1\ntest2\n")
echo test command "${args[@]}"
```

The `printf` prints `test1` and `test2`, and `echo` runs as `echo --foo test1 --foo test2`.